# Perl module to convert between MB/GB/TB without converting to bytes first?

Tags: perl, module, byte, number-formatting

I'm trying to calculate the free space on an LVM physical volume by multiplying the number of free physical extents by the extent size, for example:

```
3623365 free extents * 4.00 MB each = 13.8 TB
```

I was using [Number::Format](http://search.cpan.org/~wrw/Number-Format-1.73/Format.pm) to convert the extent size to bytes and convert the results of the multiplication back to a human-readable string, but TB and higher are not supported, so I end up with the longer, less readable `14,153.8 GB`.

According to the docs, the reason TB and up are not supported is because of integer overflows on 32-bit systems, which made me wonder if I should even be multiplying arbitrary large numbers without using something like [Math::BigInt](http://perldoc.perl.org/Math/BigInt.html). I see that [Number::Bytes::Human](http://search.cpan.org/~dagobert/Number-Bytes-Human/Human.pm) supports numbers up to YB (yottabytes), but it's still in alpha so I hesitate to use it in production code.

My next thought was, why even convert to bytes in the first place when I could calculate the free space in MB and then convert to TB? Unfortunately, it seems like neither [Number::Format](http://search.cpan.org/~wrw/Number-Format-1.73/Format.pm) nor [Number::Bytes::Human](http://search.cpan.org/~dagobert/Number-Bytes-Human/Human.pm) supports conversions from one "suffix" to another, e.g. MB -> TB. Is there an existing module that does this? I really like how [Number::Format](http://search.cpan.org/~wrw/Number-Format-1.73/Format.pm) and [Number::Bytes::Human](http://search.cpan.org/~dagobert/Number-Bytes-Human/Human.pm) handle both SI/non-SI units (MB vs. MiB), allow you to set the precision, etc. and so hesitate to roll my own solution if a similarly full-featured module already does it.

**Edit:** The extent size is not always in MB, nor is the free space always in TB, so I am not asking how to convert from MB to TB (that would be trivial). I *am* asking if there are any existing modules that can convert from one [arbitrary] suffix to another without converting to bytes first.

Answer (score 1):

To convert from MB to TB w/o going through Bytes:

Number of TB = Number of MB * (Bytes in 1 TB/Bytes in 1 MB)

---

UPDATE:
To Generalize:

Number of new units = Number of old units * (Bytes in 1 new unit / Bytes in 1 old unit)

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear in my question...I will not always be converting from MB, and do not always want to end up with TB. I want my result string to be as short as possible, which means using the appropriate suffix (GB, TB, what have you).

Comment: I don't think you're quite understanding my question. I have a value where the units are unknown until runtime (could be kB, GiB, TB, etc). This value is then multiplied by an integer that is also unknown until runtime. How do you figure out what units should be used to express the result as succinctly as possible (e.g. 9.8GB instead of 10,000MB)? There are some simple solutions on [PerlMonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=378538) but they do not take into account things like megabytes vs. mebibytes. Hence my question.

Comment: Your source units will be very limited, perhaps a score of possibilities.  Extracting it with a regex would be trivial.  After multiplication you have a value that is in, above or below your desired range (1 to 1000 or 1024).  Scale as necessary.